# Upgrade from 11.04 to 11.10, getting "W:Failed to fetch gzip..."

Tags: 11.10, 11.04, upgrade

Error during update

A problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of network problem, please check your network connection and retry.

```
W:Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric_universe_i18n_Translation-en  Encountered a section with no Package: header
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I can browse web sites normally during this time though (my network is ok).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a local file `/var/lib...`. `sudo rm` it, `sudo apt-get update` the try again. If necessary, remove the entire contents of the `partial` folder, update and try.